# Why does not `replace` replace a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following code that adds fragments to the same container `R.id.container`. First I add one fragment, then after user interacts with it, I add another one with the same code

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

My question when I cell `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()` I can see two fragments. Why doesn't `replace` actually replace but add?

Comment: It actually does replace. You must be doing something wrong but it is not apparent from the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It keeps the two fragments because

```
addToBackStack(null);
```

means the user is able to revert back to the previous state.
If you add **fragment1** (using replace), then **fragment2**, only **fragment2** is shown, but if the user press back, the FragmentManager needs to show **fragment1**, so it keeps a reference to both fragment.